# Remove whitespace/new lines/comments. Regex?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, preg-match

I'm currently making sort of a CSS minifier and well, I think examples for what I'm trying to achieve are the simplest way to explain.

I'm trying to transform this:

```
/* CSS Content */

.class{
    text-align:center;
    border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;
}

.anotherclass, .another, .another{
    text-align:center;
    border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;
}
```

Into:

```
.class{text-align:center;border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;}.anotherclass,.another,.another{text-align:center;border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;}
```

Thus: removing `comments`, unnecessary `whitespace` and `new lines`.

So far I got to remove the comments and new lines (Using one expression and a function exploding the string on `\n`, then appending the parts). The `whitespaces` are a bit more difficult, since the `whitespaces` within the `{}` should be removed but not between the `colon` and `semicolon`.

Since I'm quite inexperienced with the use of regular expressions, have no good reference book at hand and Google does'nt seem to have the answer: I'm wondering if anyone here can help me with creating one good Regex to accomplish this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: In your example, the whitespace within the `{}` *doesn't* stay intact

Comment: What you are developing is called a “minifier”.

Comment: There are existing tools for this, why are you reinventing the wheel? Just search for CSS minifier.

Comment: This is not what regex was made for. Use a parser to read the CSS.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you could try something like this:

```
(?<=[{};])\s+|\/\*.+?\*\/
```

http://rubular.com/r/djDtEPzEV0

Cleans out whitespace in front of parentheses, semicolons and all comments.

Comment: @EvdTempel There is no `\'</p>` in my code, so the problem probably stems from elsewhere. Here's a working example: http://codepad.org/TIW7h87Y

Comment: @EvdTempel Right, I'm just letting you know the regex works fine in PHP.

Answer (score 1):

If you must do it this way then this will minify the example you gave:

```
(/\*[^/]+\*/|^\t*|^\s*|\n|\s+(?=[\{.])|(?<=[\{;])\s+)
```

It assumes the flavour of regex you're using allows positive look-behinds